# Query by Buffer not working through proxy page

Tags: c#, javascript, arcgis

I have web mapping application that have most of the GIS functionality including Buffering.
My problem is that the query by buffer is not working (i.e. giving the required results) when the characters increase from 2000 in number.

I have followed all the instructions given on ArcGIS help center to install the proxy page but somehow its not working.

Comment: We're going to need to see some source code to understand your problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Figure out the Query Execution using Firefox-> Firebug tool.

Use `console.log(<some text >);` to figure out which lines are executing .